# Maven doesn't download a slf4j dependency slf4j-log4j12

Tags: spring, maven-2, slf4j

I try to use

```
slf4j-log4j12
```

library, but maven doesn't download the jar. My local .m2 repository shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDp4.png)

I'm using Apache Maven 3.5.4 with Java version: 11.0.15. The dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.3</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What could be the problem? I'm behind corporate firewall and use JFrog antifactory.

I added maven2 repo to pom.xml. Tried Invalidate Cache in IntelliJ and other cleanup I could think of.

Comment: The given pom file is only pom file which contains a redirection https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/2.0.3/pom that means you have to change your groupId/artifactId furthermore you should upgrade your Maven version

Comment: @khmarbaise - Thank you for your comment. After checked the link, I understand the problem now. But I don't follow what change should I make. Can you elaborate further about what exactly should I do?  I have maven 3.5.4 - that's fairly new, why should I upgrade maven, to which version?

Comment: Maven 3.5.4 is of 2018 (not even new or near to it.) Current version 3.8.6 .. see https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html second what you have to upgrade in your app I simply don't know..